# in Kendo, how to make a tooltip with a custom databinding?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

I'd like to show a custom tooltip when my user hovers over a node in a line chart.

In this tooltip, I need to databind to a string that is contained within the object bound in the series

In the below example, the MyObject class has three properties **Date, Point, and Point_Info**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<MyObject>()
        .Name("chart")
        .Title("")
        .DataSource(ds => 
            ds.Read(read => read.Action("_X", "Y"))
        )
        .Series(series =>
        {
            series.ScatterLine(model => model.Date, model => model.Point);
        })
        .XAxis(x=>x
            .Date()
            .Title("Date")
        )
        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
            .Visible(true)
           . Format("{1} on {0} -- #=Point_Info#")  <-- this doesnt work for me
        )
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using format use .Template("#= customTip #") where customTip is one of the properties in the model that contains the custom tooltip text. Format is much more limited and is only used for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mike!

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<MyObject>()
        .Name("chart")
        .Title("")
        .DataSource(ds => 
            ds.Read(read => read.Action("_X", "Y"))
        )
        .Series(series =>
        {
            series.ScatterLine(model => model.Date, model => model.Point).Tooltip(x=>x.Template("#=dataItem.Point_Info#"));
        })
        .XAxis(x=>x
            .Date()
            .Title("Date")
        )
        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
            .Visible(true)
        )
      )
```